# What is lm() compared to VAR()

Tags: r, regression, model, vector-autoregression, lm

What's the difference between

```
# Fit Model #
fit1 = lm(var$1 ~ var$2, data=data)
```

and

```
# Fit Model #
cof = data.frame(var$1,var$2)
fit1 = VAR(cof, p=lag, type="both")
```

I think that the first is a linear autoregressive model and that the latter is a vector autoregressive model, right? Meaning: The results should be the same, as long as the VAR does not use not more than two variables.

Comment: Is that from the VAR package?

Comment: Did you see this code in an example somewhere?

Answer (score 6):

If `var$1` and `var$2` are two distinct variables, `fit1 = lm(var$1 ~ var$2, data = data)` will give you a regression of the form

$$var_{1,t}=\beta_0+\beta_1 var_{2,t}+\varepsilon_t.$$

This is **not** an autoregression. The formula could give you an autoregression only if `var$2` were a lag of `var$1`.

Meanwhile, `fit1 = VAR(cof, p=lag, type="both")` will give you a vector autoregression of the form

$$
\begin{aligned}
var_{1,t} &= \beta_{10} + \gamma_1 t + \beta_{111} var_{1,t-1} + \beta_{112} var_{2,t-1} + \dotsc + \beta_{p11} var_{1,t-p} + \beta_{p12} var_{2,t-p} + \varepsilon_{1t} \\
var_{2,t} &= \beta_{20} + \gamma_2 t + \beta_{121} var_{1,t-1} + \beta_{122} var_{2,t-1} + \dotsc + \beta_{p21} var_{1,t-p} + \beta_{p22} var_{2,t-p} + \varepsilon_{2t}
\end{aligned}
$$

If `var$2` were a lag of `var$1`, the model would not make sense as it would specify two different processes for the same variables.

> The results should be the same, as long as the VAR does not use not more than two variables.

No. The differences between the two models are quite large.

- `lm` (as you specified it) has only one dependent variable while `VAR` (as you specified it) has two. Moreover, none of the two `VAR` equations match the `lm` equation.
- `lm` does not include lags of variables while `VAR` includes $p$ lags.
- `lm` does not include a time trend while `VAR` does.